# How to validate nested objects in rails one by one but not as scope while updating or saving?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I've run into the problem with rails validation for bulk model relations creation.

Let me show you the case

I've got 2 models: Job and Appointment, where job has_many appointments and appointment belongs to the job. Both models have `accepts_nested_attributes_for :appointments/:job`

There is the page, where the Job form is showed (`simple_form_for @job`), and this form has a nested form for appointments (`simple_fields_for :appointments`). So there is also a controller to handle job updating looks default to rails.

```
if @job.update(bulk_new_appointments_params)
  redirect_to <success_path>, notice: 'Appointments was successfully created.'
else
  render :bulk_new_appointments
end
```

This works fine. Appointments are created successfully for the job and it looks great..

But there is 1 validation Appointment model has. This validation hits the database and checks for datetime overlapping of Appointment with another Job's appointments (created before).
E.g. if you have 1 appointment to `10/10/2020 2:00PM with 2h duration` you cannot create an appointment between `2:00PM` and `4:00PM`

But if you send 2 appointments with the same datetime as something like this:

```
params: {
  job: {
    appointments_attributes: {
        1: {id:... datetime: '10/10/2020 4PM', duration: '2h' }
        2: {id:... datetime: '10/10/2020 5PM', duration: '1h' }
      }
  }
}
```

When these params come to `@job.update(attributes)` Rails first of all checks each item validation and save them then. But as I said before - we have got database level validation. So 2 new appointments with overlapped datetimes are "valid" because both of them are not recorded to the DB and overlapping check returns valid.

So now for a more precise question:
How to change the Rails default strategy for updating records?

From:

> validate them all then save them all

To:

> validate one then save one (repeat for all collection)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, but my approach was validate and reject if one was an overlap in the current job.  For that I needed a `validate` method in Appointment that would examine the job appointments.  Essentially...

```
class Appointmment
  validate :no_overlap_in_this_job

  def no_overlap_in_this_job
     return if _destroy
     job.appointments.each do |appointment|
       next if appointment == self
       if start_time < appointment.end_time && end_time > appointment.start_time
         errors.add(:base, 'this appointment overlaps another in the job')
         break
       end
     end
  end
```

This works, because the validation has access to the unsaved appointment and the unsaved appointment's jobs.  You will still want your current validation, which will check appointments in this job against overlap with other jobs.